# as running an HTML file from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have the following code in a spreadsheet, part of the script, and I want to run my HTML file called "server" from my .gs file called "code.gs".

//code.gs

```
function start()
{ 
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ui');
}

function getDriveFiles(continuationToken) 
{
  if(continuationToken) 
  {
    var files = DriveApp.continueFileIterator(continuationToken);
  }
  else
  {
    var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  }
  var i = 0;
  while (files.hasNext() && i < 10) 
  {
    var file = files.next();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow([file.getName(), file.getUrl()]);
    i++;
    if(i == 10) 
    {
      return files.getContinuationToken();
    }
  }
}
```

the program starts in the function "start()" then I want to run the "HTML" file so I continued the program but not be as.

//server.html

```
start();

<script>

function start() 
{
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getDriveFiles();
}

function onSuccess(continuationToken)
{
  if(continuationToken) 
  {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getDriveFiles(continuationToken);
  }
}

</script>
```

If you could help me I would appreciate them, previous mind was doing it with this function.

```
function start() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ui');
  return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

and executing the program but with a sidebar, but at the moment of putting an activator, run at a certain time not is executed by that could not run the "getUi" function in that environment.
then what I do is remove the part of the sidebar and do it direct.
I hope you can understand me, i write from México

Comment: The third line of server.gs should be var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('server');  to use the html file, not 'ui' as there's no ui.html file

Comment: already change the function                                                                    function start()
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('server');
}                                                                                                                                 but does not run the html file